# Setup cloadmin on Centos installed in LVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, lvm, partition

I installed CentOS 6 with default LVM partition pattern. according to this pattern Can I use Cloudmin and store KVM Disks in LVM as Logical Volume?

Comment: [Also posted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53296/setup-cloadmin-on-centos-installed-in-lvm). Please [do not post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073).